# Convert/compile a string into executable code in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection, objective-c-runtime

I want to take a string in ObjC and evaluate it as if it were code. For example (these are made-up functions):

```
NSString *Cmd=@" if (10>5) NSLog(@"Test");  ";
MyClass.Run(Cmd);
```

I expect that "Test" appears in the output log. I have searched and tested a lot of code samples and library but still no good results.

I Ended Up with these 2 libraries for compilation at runtime:

1- libClang framework and clang_Cursor_Evaluate function .

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-01-24-introduction-to-libclang.html

https://github.com/root-project/cling

2- objc-eval framework .

https://github.com/antipax/objc-eval/blob/master/README.mdown

I could not do anything with libClang. and left as it is for now, but with the second one, I successfully compiled the framework and actually used it in a simple project, however still no proper output!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OEEvaluation.h"
void main()
{
Code1:OEEvaluation *evaluation = [OEEvaluation evaluationWithCode:@"retun @\"Hello World!\" ;" delegate:nil];
Code2://OEEvaluation *evaluation = [OEEvaluation evaluationWithCode:@"NSLog(@\"Hello World!\");" delegate:nil];
NSLog([evaluation evaluateSynchronously]);
NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

No output with Code1 and Code 2: no (null), no error, no hint.. nothing at all.

Code 1 is the exact sample from the framework's documentation.

Maybe I am wrong but I think the solutions I found are the closest ones to the answer between my researches.

Now the questions are:

1- How can I accomplish this idea (convert a string into an executable line of executable code)?

2- How can I get the objc-eval.framework to work?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get the objc-eval.framework to work?

The full source is available, work your way through it.

You will discover that it runs your code by splicing it into an Xcode project that it creates by unpacking a `tar` archive, calling `xcodebuild` to compile that project, and then dynamically loading the compiled code and executing it.

Your first problem is that the tar'ed archive is rather old and needs updating for the latest version of Xcode – Xcode provides the option to do this. Having done that the project will compile but you'll find the compiled code is not where this framework expects to find it – this is because by default the project settings which set the location of the products are overridden in the latest versions of Xcode.

You need to explore Xcode's `Preferences…`, the project's `Build Locations` settings, the arguments the `xcodebuild` command takes, and the code in the framework which loads the compiled binary to decide which settings will get the compiled binary where you want it so the framework can access it.

Once you do that you'll find the framework works. Note that for this to work at all requires Xcode to be installed on any system your app runs on.

Have fun!

HTH

Comment: the most important part of your answer is the final part. do you mean that objc-eval.framwork not works on iphone devices? because there is no Xcode Installed???i need this project to be run on iphone devices. @CRD

Comment: @Mrjm - Correct, the objc-eval framework relies on having Xcode installed, as does your other option libClang, and so neither will work under iOS. Objective-C is usually a compiled language and even if you find or write an interpreter for it you may find Apple's iOS rules disallow it in a shipping app. I think you need to re-evaluate what you are doing and your requirement to dynamically compile Objective-C.

Comment: @CRD-thanks, saved me a lot of time - now im trying to achive this idea with Javascript . found  https://github.com/evgenyneu/ios-javascriptcore-demo .
its small,Clean,good and runs Fine,But it appears to be for simple Js codes Only and there is no access on Native Codes and device functionality s. any idea or suggestions around it?

Comment: @Mrjm - iOS apps run in a *sandbox*, JavaScript runs in a *sandbox* - attempting to give users on-the-fly general access to "device functionality" does not sound like it fits this model. Maybe you should think again. That said JavaScript can call into Objective-C and Swift. Documentation for JavaScriptCore is sparse, but spending some time searching the web will turn up examples. Have fun!